# How can I add a CSS class to the body tag?

Tags: theming, 8

I'm trying to add a custom CSS class to the `<body>` tag, How can I modify or pre-process the `<body>` tag to add the class body, Is it right to style the `<body>` tag with css file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**If html.html.twig does not exist in your current theme's template folder**, go to `/core/modules/system/templates` folder.

Open **html.html.twig** file. Highlight and copy all code (CTRL + A then CTRL + C)

Go to your theme's template folder `/themes/[yourtheme]/templates` and create a new file called **html.html.twig**, open and paste (CTRL + V) the code you copied.

Change `<body{{ attributes }}>` to `<body{{ attributes.addClass('my-class') }}>`

Clear/Flush the cache to see changes.

Comment: Is different from the copy and past the `html.html.twig` file?

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani if it already exists, it **may** be different as some modification could've been made. All it means is that you just skip the copy paste part and just edit the html.html.twig and change to attributes part, if you already have a html.html.twig file in your theme's template folder.

Answer (score 32):

Alternatively, you could implement `template_preprocess_html` in your [themename].theme file.

```
function themename_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'class-name';
}
```

See the documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8.2.x

Comment: Just for understanding, could you please describe where shall I put the 'body' and 'myclassname'. will it be like `$variables['attributes']['body'][] = 'myClassNameForBody'`

Comment: @CodeNext if you open html.html.twig you will see that the `{{ attributes }}` variable gets printed inside the body tag, as you can also see in the snipped of my answer. Therefore, you already know this affects the body.

Comment: @NoSssweat, Thx for input. I got your answer, which is straight forward to understand. I would like to understand this way of doing. Suppose I want my <body> class `class-name`, Do I have to add @Josh's answer as it is provided or I have to modify something? If I do not have to modify then how it will address specifically to <body>? Again Thx.

Comment: @CodeNext as provided. Here is the explanation: `<body{{ attributes }}>` as you can see `{{ attributes }}` is inside `<body ... >`. @Josh's code modifies the attributes array and adds a class-name under the `class` array. **Side Note:** you should recognise that $variables is a multi dimensional array.

Comment: @NoSssweat, Ok, I understand..Thanks you...So ultimately it is function `themename_preprocess_html(&$variables)` which does this job of placing the `class-name` in the body and that class name is saved in `attributes` array. Thx.

Comment: This is, to me, the preferred approach.

Comment: The field value I'm looking to add to the body class isn't showing up in the variables array. I'm assuming because the field is disabled in the manage view ui. How can I get the field value to stick into the class array?

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
 * Add a "nodeType-detail-page" class to the body on a offer detail page
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if($node) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'node-'. $node->bundle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the [Page Specific Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_specific_class) module to add class to body tag of any page. From the module page:

> It is a simple module for Drupal 8 users to add custom CSS class to
>   the  tag of the any specific page
>
> Features
>
> - We can add class to body tag of any page
> - Support all Pages which can be created via Node, Views or Custom Route
> - We can add class for Home page also
> - We can add class for All pages also

*Disclaimer, I am the author of the module.*

Comment: Disclaimer: You are the author of this module. Problem: It doesn't have any release out at the moment. Not even a dev.

Comment: Thanks leymannx , i was planning to release today only release for this module . It is up now please check now

Comment: @HardikPatel Your original post was essentially a link only answer. For module recommendations, we typically ask that people include a short snippet about the module (the module description can be good) except for ones that are very common, and a little about how the module can solve the problem.  We also ask that people disclose their connections to modules, blog posts, etc.  Self-promotion (within reason) is OK, just let everyone know.  I edited the post for a head start for you, but add any more details that you feel would help.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple way to add a class based on the URL, in Drupal 9. It doesn't require any module.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  // Get the current path
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $internal = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);

  // Assign it to body class 
  $vars['attributes']['class'][] = str_replace("/", "", $internal);
}
```

Comment: `template_preprocess_html` has been posted already. And there's `\Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::cleanCssIdentifier($internal)` to get a proper CSS class.