# Hide Admin Toolbar in iFrame

Tags: toolbar, 8

Is it somehow possible within Drupal 8 to hide the Admin Toolbar when the site is loaded within an iFrame? Like e.g. passing an argument? :-)

I thought about using some sort of preprocess on the page that is getting rendered within the iFrame, but this will not work since the html is cached by Drupal.
Also I thought about doing it within Javascript, but I do not want to include a javascript file on every page but default.

Maybe someone knows a hook_() which will allow me to manipulate the css but is not getting cached?

Comment: can you use a different theme for admin/user? https://www.drupal.org/project/toolbar_visibility

Comment: No, since this is an implementation for a contrib module, I do not want to force the users to install another theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a similar approach as @Hudri and access the site as `https://www.mysite.com?is_iframe=true`.

Then, add a class to the body tag if the request option is there:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $is_iframe = \Drupal::request()->query->get('is_iframe');
  if ($is_iframe === 'true') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'hide-admin-toolbar';
  }
}
```

If I remember correctly, Drupal will regenerate the HTML when you access `https://www.mysite.com?is_iframe=true` vs `https://www.mysite.com`.

---

References:

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/207046/56157
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/210379/56157

Comment: Great solution! I assume you're using CSS to hide the toolbar. That can get a bit gnarly if you're also using admin_toolbar. Another option would be to prevent it from rendering at all, e.g.:

`if ($is_iframe === 'true') { if (isset($variables['page_top']['toolbar'])) { unset($variables['page_top']['toolbar']); }}`

Answer (score 2):

This should be doable with a [cache context](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-contexts):

Drupal core already provides a cache context
`url.query_args`
which can be used for your query parameter, e.g. an URL
`https://www.mysite.com?is_iframe=true`
would be a cache context
`\Drupal::service('cache_context.url.query_args')->getContext('is_iframe');`

AFAIK the cache_context `url.query_args` is already enabled by default in Drupal core, so you only need to add this cache context to the render array in an appropriate preprocess function.

Note that cache contexts generally do not work with Internal Page Cache module!

For production you should finetune this with a more specific, custom cache-context `url.query_args:my_query_param` to limit unnecessary cache contexts (dumb bots could trigger a gazillion cache context calculations otherwise)